# No flow definition found. Spring web flow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I am new to Spring webflow and now I am trying the example in Spring recipes book and I know this is a basic question.

I am getting the error as follows,

```
    org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.NoSuchFlowDefinitionException: No flow definition '${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=next' found
    at org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl.getFlowDefinitionHolder(FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl.java:126)
    at org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl.getFlowDefinition(FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl.java:61)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:138)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:193)....
```

Shown below is my configurations,

```
    <bean name="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"></property>
    </bean>

    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" />

    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" >
        <webflow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/flows/welcome/welcome.xml"></webflow:flow-location>
    </webflow:flow-registry>
```

/WEB-INF/flows/welcome/welcome.xml,

```
<view-state id="welcome">
    <transition on="next" to="introduction" />
    <transition on="skip" to="menu" />
</view-state>

<view-state id="introduction">
    <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="libraryService.getHolidays()" result="requestScope.holidays" />
    </on-render>
    <transition on="next" to="menu" />
</view-state>

<view-state id="menu"></view-state>
```

In welcome.jsp,

```
    <a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=next">Next</a>
    <a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=skip">Skip</a>
```

Please let me know what is going wrong. I am using 2.0.9 Release.

Thanks in advance,
SD

Answer (score 0):

You act as you had entered the `welcome` flow, but you haven't. Try to create index.html file in the root of your project and put the following link there (for user to manually enter your app)

```
<a href="welcome">Enter application</a>
```

... or following to navigate to your flow automatically:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=spring/welcome"/>
</head>
</html>
```

... where `spring` is the url pattern of your Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet in your web.xml (lets say

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map all /spring requests to the Dispatcher Servlet for handling -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the values of ${flowExecutionKey} is not getting populated. Try this

```
<c:out value='${flowExecutionKey}'/>
```

so welcome.jsp will look like

```
<a href="<c:out value='${flowExecutionKey}'/>&_eventId=next">Next</a><a href="<c:out value='${flowExecutionKey}'/>&_eventId=skip">Skip</a>
```